# Angular getAccessToken to use in header, 401 issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, httprequest, access-token

Am doing a spa in Angular5 and want to authenticate against azure's active directory (oidc)and then be able to send a post/get request using the accessToken as a header but can't get it to work.

Now I need to understand if this accesstoken is wrong and if I should include something else in the header?

I get the accesstoken after having been redirected to a microsoft login page that redirects me back to my localhost (my app.component.ts ngOnInit below) in which I log and save the accesstoken via the code below.

```js
async ngOnInit() {
 this.ConfigureAuth();
  this.oauthService.tryLogin({});

  if (!this.oauthService.getAccessToken()) {
    await this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
  }
  console.log(this.oauthService.getAccessToken());

   this.tokenJ =  this.oauthService.getAccessToken().toString();
  console.log('getAccessToken ' + this.tokenJ);

  console.log('tid till expiration ' + this.oauthService.getAccessTokenExpiration());

  console.log(this.oauthService.authorizationHeader());



}
```

I log the accesstoken 3 times to the console, the authorizationHeader is the same as the getAccessToken. 
The accessToken look something like "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI......"

Now when I want to access an API on Azure for which I got the accessToken by sending in client id etc in ConfigureAuth(), I use a get-request and attach the accesstoken in header but get back 401-response unauthorized.

Could somebody please explain if the first accessToken is only there to get another accessToken to be allowed to call the api? If so how do I get the correct token to send as a header in my api-request?

Please help me fill in the blanks by asking for clarification if I have not been specific enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a JWT accesstoken back from the login page. 
This JWT token should as I have already done be sent in the header.

The issue was that the backend did not validate the token, hence the request failed. With other words, the front end was already working and the problem was validating the jwt from the backend.

" When the user makes API calls to the application, the user passes the JWT along with the API call. In this setup, the application server would be configured to verify that the incoming JWT are created by the authentication server (the verification process will be explained in more detail later). So, when the user makes API calls with the attached JWT, the application can use the JWT to verify that the API call is coming from an authenticated user."  [source](https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec)